# Having error (NullPointerexception : Attemp to de-reference Null)

Tags: apex, class, account, dml, dmlexception

I am trying my best with this code but don't know why i am getting error

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

can you please tell me that what i have did wrong.

```
public class AccountHandler {

    public static Account insertNewAccount (String accName){

    if(accName != '' && accName != null){    
        Account a = new Account();
            a.Name = 'TrailHead';
            a.date__c = Date.today();
            insert a;

        try{
            insert a;
            return a;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.Debug('Account not created');
            return null;
        }
    } 
      return null;  
    }    
}
```

Comment: You really trying to insert twice or a mistake while posting?

Comment: ohh yes. did mistake while posting. just remove that insert a; below the try.

Comment: Check for any missing required fields on `Account`. Try checking for null first in `if` condition. i.e. `if( accName != null && accName != '')`

Comment: Check the error message to confirm which line it is happening on as this will tell you the problem. Remember that this function can return null as an account so if you are using the returned account elsewhere you may be de-referencing a null object there.

Comment: Actually my requirement is (create an Apex class that inserts a new account named after an incoming parameter. If the account is successfully inserted, the method should return the account record. If a DML exception occurs, the method should return null.) does this code make sense ?

Comment: Can you share your line number in which you are getting exception. As Doug suggest you need to check that also. This piece of code looks ok.

Comment: @Tushar, I am not getting error in my class but i am fulfilling the challenge in SALESFORCE TRAILHEAD. when i clicked on Check Challenge (Button). at that time the y will give me an error.

Comment: @Nihar can you post the challenge link.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_database/apex_database_dml#challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. it will complete the challenge.

```
public class AccountHandler {

    public static Account insertNewAccount (String accName){
       try{
            Account a = new Account();
            a.Name = accName;
            insert a;
            return a;
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.Debug('Account not created');
            return null;
        }

    }    
}
```

and if you have any other required field in account then fill that value also and check challenge.

Comment: This will work.

Comment: Actually i did this before your answer but at that time i was not using my require field. (That is my silly mistake). any way thanks a lot to get me to the challenge. :)

Comment: happy to help :)